# Should there be a 'do' here? - "Trying to figure out what (do) I enjoy doing."

Tags: word-usage, do

Should there be a 'do' in this sentence?

"Trying to figure out what (do) I enjoy doing."

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No,  there shouldn't.

Comment: That's not really a sentence, it's a fragment. You could include "do" in that phrase in contexts like these, which involve a distinction between "what I enjoy doing" and "what I don't enjoy doing": "None of my former hobbies give me pleasure anymore; these days, I don't enjoy fishing, reading, or listening to music. In fact, I've been trying to figure out what I do enjoy doing." "Thirty years of working sixteen-hour days as a copy editor have given me a clear enough idea of what I don't enjoy doing; now I'm trying to figure out what I do enjoy doing."

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phenomenon you're asking about is [Do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support). It happens with questions when there's no other auxiliary, but *not* with embedded clauses, even when they would seem like they would be questions:

I enjoy doing X.
What do I enjoy doing?
I am trying to figure out what I enjoy doing.

I left early.
Did I leave early?
He knows if I left early.

I went to Canada.
When did I go to Canada?
I forgot when I went to Canada.

Comment: thank you. appreciate the detailed answer! :)